# How to set custom response in Servlet Filter on Spring Boot 3? (Response seems to be replaced later)

Tags: spring, servlet-filters, spring-boot-3

I have this Filter class in Spring Boot 3:

```
@Component
public class AcknowledgeFilter implements jakarta.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // does not work
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(500, "my-error-message");

        // does not work
        // response.getWriter().write("my-error-message");
        // response.getWriter().flush();
        // or response.getWriter().close();

        // does not work either
        response.getOutputStream().write("my-error-message".getBytes());
        return;
    }
}
```

The method returns without calling `chain.doFilter()` but just with setting the error response, the proper HTTP code is returned (500 or 404, ...) but never the response message I set (here "my-error-message").
I always get an JSON response like:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-10-17T15:05:12.825+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "path": "/api/myrequest/path"
}
```

Where does this message come from and how can I overwrite it?

**Update**

I turned on debug logging

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/order/last?customerNumber=123

o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/api/error]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/error?customerNumber=123
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/error?customerNumber=123
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/api/error?customerNumber=123", parameters={masked}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
c.a.c.c.c.EndpointLoggingInterceptor     : Endpoint /api/error called
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

This shows, that after the error is returned, it is processed by the `BasicErrorController`. It seems to be necessary, to register a custom ErrorController.

Comment: If you remove the chain.doFilter(request, customResponseWrapper); line from your CustomResponseFilter and don't call chain.doFilter, it will prevent the request from being processed further down the filter chain. This is because calling chain.doFilter is essential to continue the filter chain execution, allowing the request to proceed to the servlet or other filters in the chain. As the previous, the result out of your expected  is that you prevent the request continue processing ,  so  spring  would  wrapper the response in default format , not your  customized error message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to overwrite Spring Boots `BaseErrorController`:

```
import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.DefaultErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}")
public class ErrorController extends BasicErrorController {
    public ErrorController() {
        super(new DefaultErrorAttributes(), new ErrorProperties());
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String message = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            final HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(message, headers, status);
        }
        return super.error(request);
    }
}
```

This is certainly not perfect, but was a quick solution that works.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `@ControllerAdvice`

Here is an example

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String triggerError() {
        throw new CustomException("This is a custom exception message.");
    }

    @GetMapping("/ok")
    public String ok() {
        return "Everything is fine.";
    }
}
```

Based on this code, you can create controller advisor that will catch your response and transit to your needs

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> handleCustomException(CustomException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(SomeObject.builder().message(e.getMessage()).build(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // you can build your 
    }

    // You can add more exception handlers for other types of exceptions here.

    // You can also define global model attributes here using @ModelAttribute.
}
```

Use `Lombok` library for builder creation

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already do have a `ControllerAdvice`, but it doesn't react to an exception thrown in the Filter. I think it doesn't catch exceptions thrown already in a `Filter` class, but only exceptions thrown after the controller was called.